# How to include new data into existing algorithm?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, inference, ensemble-learning

I have a complex ensembel algorithm X (divide data with k means that learn ensembel for each subgroup). Learning time of X is approx. 20 hours. I cannot afford to relearn algorithm for every new observation, but I would like to use new information that it present.

What is the best way to include new information? Can I somehow infer new information in existing algorithm (if needed I can provide more detailed description of it)?

I have looked into the infering neural network (i have never worked with them before), but I am not sure that I understand it correctly. Would it be possible to build a deep NN (or ensemble) on train data, and then set up inference on  test data? Can I just update testdata and re run inference, would that work? Or am I completly missing the point here?

I have not find much literature on inference, so I would be thankful for any references or brainstorming ideas.

Specs:

- R (prefer) or python (can run NN on GPU)
- i7-8850 processor; 6-core, 1050GTX NVIDIA, 32GB RAM, windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Do you mean [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning)?

Comment: I cannot understand the relation of the third paragraph to the rest of the question. Do you *also* want to do inference, or are you confused about the meaning of the word? In case of the former, it does not seem related to the rest of your question, so it would be better suited as a separate question.

Comment: It was just like regular wondering if that  would be a better approach to the problem. And that online learning is helpful, thanks.

Comment: For example I was wondering that: Algortihm says that output is class 0, but later I found out that it is really class 1. So now I know that for that observation I made a mistake. How can add that knowledge to my existing algorithm X?